# onClick functions to calculate simple math

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate simple math after I click the button using javascript and yes it like onClick function with parameters then simple math. I'm sorry that I'm a beginner in JavaScript

The code is this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction(4,3)">sasd</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function myFunction(p1, p2) {
        x1= p1 * p2;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: before `function myFunction` you have to declare `x1` like `var x1;` so it's a global variable, and not local to your function

Comment: Your code looks like an example from the w3schools website.  You might also try the tutorial that mozilla offers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps

Comment: Why did you place the last statement outside the function? Also declare x1 as var inside the function. Try not to use global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its absolutely correct. Just put that last line inside the function. Here you are calling the function on click, but its not getting appended at that time. Its outside and its called at the beginning.

The correct solution will be:

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) { 
  x1= p1 * p2; 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution using `jQuery`

```js
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  $('#demo').html(p1 * p2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction(4,3)">Click ME!!!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @CalaydoMinds Welcome buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do the write in the same function that you do the math

```js
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  var x1= p1 * p2;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(4,3)">sasd</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable x1 was not defined,
Please check the fixed code below

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction(4,3)">sasd</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      function myFunction(p1, p2) {
        var x1= p1 * p2;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declare the `x1` variable.try with below code

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction(4,3)">sasd</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      var x1;
      function myFunction(p1, p2) {
        x1= p1 * p2;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
```

Put this line of code inside  script tag after this code `x1= p1 * p2`

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;` inside function. Like this:

```
<script>
  function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    var x1= p1 * p2;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x1;
  }
</script>
```